# Http.Context.Current.User null on weird URL in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, iis-8

On normal requests (e.g. /Home/Index) I get anonymous user back from

Http.Context.Current.User

And everything works in my app. But in error log I have found out Null Ref Exceptions when some bots access /+i()+ address. In debug I have found that on that page the user is null. Any idea why? Whats the difference between the two requests? I have narrowed it down to even accessing just /+ on my webserver to cause this Null Ref Exception.

Im interested in the difference between the requests. Obviously I just put in ?.  and the exception goes away.

Using IIS on Windows 2012, MVC 5, .Net 4.6, C#

Comment: Have you debugged? Run each request in a debug session and inspect the differences. However, this is mostly a waste of your time. If the URL is not valid, then returning a 500 is acceptable. Server errors are actually valid responses in some cases. You don't have to always fix them, if it *should* actually be an error.

Comment: Thanks, Well the only difference I can spot is the the user being null. I was wondering if there is some logic behind when this variable is set and when it is not (or in broader scope, if this is some kind of different type of handling altogether). But seems like it is not very common to go into this level of detail.